# Javascript && formatting Days

Tags: javascript, var, calculated-columns, days

I am new to programming, please be easy with me.

I am using Informer (a reporting website) which pulls data in from Datatel (a unidata database)

I am working on a computed column. The computed column ONLY accepts Javascript NO other language.

What the column should do:

"If the classes are on Mon & Tue & Wed & Thur & Fri
then 
display Mon-Fri"

So if the classes fall on all the week days I want to abbreviate the output to only display "Mon-Fri" instead of listing out all the days.

What the code is actually doing:
displaying Mon-Fri for every class even if it doesn't meet on those days.

Here is the code I have: which does not work

```
//declare variables
var mon = secmonday[1];
var tue = sectuesday[1];
var wed = secwednesday[1];
var thur = secthursday[1];
var fri = secfriday[1];
var formatDays = "";


//if monday through friday = Y (Y is the value in the database) 
//then format with a - in between days

if ((mon && tue && wed && thur && fri) == "Y");
{
formatDays="Mon-Fri";
}
else
{
// if any of the days fields are empty then do not display formatDays
//instead leave    
blank
if ((mon || tue ||wed || thur || fri) == null);
}
formatDays=mon+tue+wed+thur+fri;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help in advance.

---

Disregard I figured out a solution:

```
//define variables
var days = courseSections6_csmdaysk;
var output = "";
var formatDays = "Mon-Fri";
//removes whitespace within data
var formatBlank = days.replace(/\s+/g, '');

//if all days are present then display Mon-Fri
if (days == "M T W TH F")
{
output = formatDays;
}
else
{
output = formatBlank;
}
output
```

Comment: use == for comparison, not =

Comment: Yeah sorry, i noticed after i posted. I have corrected the code to compare using ==

Answer (score 0):

In `if` you neither want to assign, nor want to end condition after the first comparison and go for syntax error. And otherwise use javascript syntax when doing javascript.

```
if( mon && tue && wed && thur && fri ) formatDays = mon+'-'+fri.
```

Note, that I  believe it may yield something like `true-true` but lack the information to help you any further.

Comment: Correct, I changed my code since Y is the value in the database. I set if ="Y" the formatDays = "Mon-Fri";

Comment: NVM I figured it out:  SOLUTION                                                       //define variables
var days = courseSections6_csmdaysk;
var output = "";
var formatDays = "Mon-Fri";
//removes whitespace within data
var formatBlank = days.replace(/\s+/g, '');

//if all days are present then display Mon-Fri
if (days == "M T W TH F")
{
output = formatDays;
}
else
{
output = formatBlank;
}
output